# Dynamically setting bg image with viewgroup.layoutparams

Tags: android, viewgroup

I have a grid view that I reuse a few times in an app.  Separate activities drive what data appears. I would like to set different bg images for each activity.

What I would like to do is avoid creating multiple layouts by using viewgroup.layoutparams.

Currently, I have this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.grid_view);
```

But I would like to have something like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.grid_view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.View_background(R.drawable.background1));
```

Only one issue:  there is no View_background layout parm...

This is an RTM but I can't seem to find it.  Anyone know what it is? Is there one?

Answer (score 3):

You can not change background using LayoutParams. Instead, assign an ID to the root view in your XML file and use this code to change the background:
`findViewById(R.id.your_view).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background1);`